# Angular 2 bind to computed getter gives debug erros

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, decorator, lodash

I am working with Angular 2 and lodash.

I have a model with Relations and I have a getter like that:

```
get relationsPerType() {
    return _(this.Relations)
        .groupBy(p => p.Type)
        .toPairs()
        .map(p => ({
            type: <MessageRelationType>p[0],
            relations: <Relation[]>p[1]
        }));
}
```

Binding the value of relationsPerType to an *ngFor directive

*Edit: This is my binding:*

```
<div *ngFor="#relationGroup of Message.relationsPerType">
    ...
</div>
```

Gives me the following error:

> Expression 'Message.relationsPerType in MessagesDetailsComponent@60:8'
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous

which seems to be perfectly right as indeed this is computed each and every time it is called.

In any case, having "computed" variables like that I can't imagine how Angular 2 change detection could detect that relationsPerType has actually changed.
Something like marking the getter as immutable??

I suppose a better way would be:

a) To store the computed getter values inside a property right from start

b) To make the parent object Immutable so as for Angular to not track changes on properties

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I found a better way using **decorators**, than a) and b) has to offer, as:

a) I don't want to loose the "lazy" computations that getter functions provide and make everything a property

b) Immutable IS a viable solution but not applicable to my case

So, coming from C# and lots of Aspect Oriented programming (see PostSharp), I finally managed to create a **cached property getter decorator** function that is evaluated only once per object:

```
function cachedProperty(target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    let originalGetter = descriptor.get;
    descriptor.get = function () {
        let cachSetted = this[`__cachedsetted${key}`];
        if (typeof cachSetted !== 'undefined') {
            return this[`__cached${key}`];
        }
        this[`__cachedsetted${key}`] = true;

        return this[`__cached${key}`] = originalGetter.call(this);
    }
}
```

after that all that needs to change is decorate the getter with the @cachedProperty decorator, like so:

```
    @cachedProperty
    get relationsPerType() {
        return _(this.Relations)
            .groupBy(p => p.Type)
            .toPairs()
            .map(p => ({
                type: <MessageRelationType>p[0],
                relations: <Relation[]>p[1]
            })).value();
    }
```

Using this decorator the object will change only once so as for the Angular 2 dependency injection not to complaint. Also, I don't loose the "lazy" evaluations, and I don't add helper properties that changes my schema.

One must of course handle the case where he wants to invalidate the cache if this becomes stale. That would require to remove the

```
`__cachedsetted${key}`
```

property from this.

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the value and bind to the cached value instead or create an observable that emits new events when data changes.

If you bind to `{{relationsPerType}}` a new collection is created every time Angular checks if a change happend and Angular sees this as change because it gets two different instances, even though they might contain the same data.

```
calcRelationsPerType() {
    this relationsPerType = _(this.Relations)
        .groupBy(p => p.Type)
        .toPairs()
        .map(p => ({
            type: <MessageRelationType>p[0],
            relations: <Relation[]>p[1]
        }));
}
```

then binding like this should work fine:

```
<div *ngFor="#relationGroup of Message.relationsPerType">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Günter! I think that there is a typo in your first snippet: `this relationsPerType = return _(this.Relations)` ;-)

Comment: Thanks Günter. What you say is actualy "a) To store the computed getter values inside a property right from start" with much additional effort to call the calcRelationsPerType() before data gets binded.

Comment: Hard to tell if it's much effort from the info you provided in the question. You need to find a way to get it recalculated when values change the result depends on. The simplest to understand solution is IMHO what I show in my answer. More advanced would be using observables. Your decorator approach is also interesting but I think invalidating the cache is quite similar to invoke recalculation.

Comment: Günter, you are right about invalidating the cache. Observables would be also a nice option there.